# pyfmi fails with Stepsize must be non-negative and divisible by 0.2'

Tags: simulink, fmi, pyfmi

I did the world's simplest simulink model which sums two constants and send the result to an outport. I exported this to an fmu model and try to run it in pyfmi.

I get an error with
FMUException: The simulation failed. See the log for more information. Return flag 3

The log says
['FMIL: module = FMILIB, log level = 5: Allocating FMIL context',
'FMIL: module = FMILIB, log level = 5: Parsing model description XML',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 5: Parsing XML element fmiModelDescription',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 5: Parsing XML element CoSimulation',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 5: Parsing XML element VendorAnnotations',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 5: Parsing XML element ModelVariables',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 4: [Line:31] Detected during parsing:',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 2: Start attribute is required for this causality, variability and initial combination',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 5: Building alias index',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 5: Parsing XML element ModelStructure',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 5: Parsing XML element Outputs',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 5: Parsing XML element InitialUnknowns',
'FMIL: module = FMILIB, log level = 5: Parsing finished successfully',
"FMIL: module = FMILIB, log level = 4: Loading 'linux64' binary with 'default' platform types",
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Loaded FMU binary from /tmp/bruce/JModelica.org/jm_tmp9uvk5t3l/binaries/linux64/simple_sum2const.so',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Loading functions for the co-simulation interface',
'FMIL: module = FMILIB, log level = 5: Successfully loaded all the interface functions',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 3: fmi2_xml_get_default_experiment_tolerance: returning default value, since no attribute was defined in modelDescription',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2SetupExperiment',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2EnterInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2ExitInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] getReal vr:0, value:5.000000',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] getReal vr:1, value:0.000000',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] CommunicationStepSize=0.02, LocalSolverStepSize=0.2',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 2: [error][FMU status:Error] Stepsize must be non-negative and divisible by 0.2',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] CommunicationStepSize=1, LocalSolverStepSize=0.2',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] Local solver will do 5 steps from t = 0.',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 3: fmi2_xml_get_default_experiment_tolerance: returning default value, since no attribute was defined in modelDescription',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2SetupExperiment',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2EnterInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2ExitInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] getReal vr:0, value:5.000000',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] getReal vr:1, value:0.000000',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] CommunicationStepSize=0.02, LocalSolverStepSize=0.2',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 2: [error][FMU status:Error] Stepsize must be non-negative and divisible by 0.2',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2SetupExperiment',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 3: fmi2_xml_get_default_experiment_tolerance: returning default value, since no attribute was defined in modelDescription',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2SetupExperiment',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2EnterInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2ExitInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] getReal vr:0, value:5.000000',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] getReal vr:1, value:0.000000',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] CommunicationStepSize=0.02, LocalSolverStepSize=0.2',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 2: [error][FMU status:Error] Stepsize must be non-negative and divisible by 0.2',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2EnterInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2ExitInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2EnterInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2ExitInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 3: fmi2_xml_get_default_experiment_tolerance: returning default value, since no attribute was defined in modelDescription',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2SetupExperiment',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2EnterInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2ExitInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] getReal vr:0, value:5.000000',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] getReal vr:1, value:0.000000',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] CommunicationStepSize=0.02, LocalSolverStepSize=0.2',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 2: [error][FMU status:Error] Stepsize must be non-negative and divisible by 0.2',
'FMIL: module = FMI2XML, log level = 3: fmi2_xml_get_default_experiment_tolerance: returning default value, since no attribute was defined in modelDescription',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2SetupExperiment',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2EnterInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = FMICAPI, log level = 5: Calling fmi2ExitInitializationMode',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] getReal vr:0, value:5.000000',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] getReal vr:1, value:0.000000',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [info][FMU status:OK] CommunicationStepSize=0.004, LocalSolverStepSize=0.2',
'FMIL: module = Model, log level = 2: [error][FMU status:Error] Stepsize must be non-negative and divisible by 0.2']

I can't find any information on how to set stepsize, or what it should be. I tried
model.do_step(0, 1.0)
model.initialize(0, 0.1, True)

model.simulate_options() shows
{'ncp': 500,
'initialize': True,
'stop_time_defined': False,
'write_scaled_result': False,
'result_file_name': '',
'result_handling': 'binary',
'result_handler': None,
'result_store_variable_description': True,
'return_result': True,
'time_limit': None,
'filter': None,
'silent_mode': False}

How can I get this simple demo to work?

Comment: Please provide more information on the FMU.
Can you share the original Simulink model and more important the FMU?
How did you generate it?

Comment: It looks as though your FMU expects a macro timestep of 0,2s but is run with a macro timestep of 0,1s